# What is the structure of Cl₂O₆?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure

I couldn't find which of these is correct and even someone I asked said there's no general covincement on it, but I'm unsure whether he's correct?
[image]

I reproduced the second structure a little wrong maybe, but arrangement and bonds are correct(I think there should be no charge on oxygen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dichlorine hexoxide has different structures depending upon whether it is in the gas or solid phase. In the gas phase, the molecule adopts structure (a) ([reference 1](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic00283a009), [reference 2](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mtth5g59dEIC&pg=PA463&lpg=PA463&dq=dichlorine%20hexoxide%20gas%20phase%20structure&source=bl&ots=tEVPfCPZNw&sig=IANaKmFXtF1w-3Z8GL-p9N4iNmU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ar54VMyxK9CUsQS88YKIAg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=dichlorine%20hexoxide%20gas%20phase%20structure&f=false)).  It is a relatively unstable molecule having a half-life measured in minutes.

[image]

In the solid phase it exists as the dark-red ionic material as shown in (b) and is often referred to as chloryl perchlorate.  Both forms are very strong oxidizing agents and react explosively with organic compunds.

Comment: the first refernce is only the reliable source but it also lists only the possible structure(NB i can read only the first page)

Comment: The second reference verifies the first reference; if you'd like to see the first reference in its entirety you can visit an academic library or purchase the article on line - your choice.  I provided the answer to your question.